# How to expand my main partition disk space?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, disk-space, disk-utility

I have a VPS (running Ubuntu 16.04 64 bits) I can only access remotely through SSH. Now, my main partition has no more free space while there are around 50GB available on another partition. I'm trying to find a way to expand my main partition even if I might lose data on this partition. Here's an overview of the current disk usage:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           780M   25M  755M   4% /run
/dev/vda1        39G   39G   51M 100% /
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           100K     0  100K   0% /run/lxcfs/controllers
/dev/vdb         50G   52M   47G   1% /mnt/vdb
tmpfs           780M     0  780M   0% /run/user/0
```

you notice the 100% space usage on **/dev/vda1** which is around 40GB size and I'd like to use the 50GB available on **/dev/vdb** to get more room.

Any idea how to do that ?

Comment: Quick Workaround. Move some data to `/dev/vdb` (a whole directory) and create a link to that directory  instead of the original one. E.g. `mv /home/user/DirWith40GB  /mnt/vbd/Dir2`  then from `/home/user`  you can do the link `ln -s /mnt/vbd/Dir2  DirWith40GB` (so you restore the original name...).

Comment: You're welcome, now I put as answer with some words more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose a **quick workaround:** *to move a whole directory with a lot of data from the jammed partition to the empty one, then to create a link to that directory in place of the original one*.

In your case, let's suppose you have a big storage data `DirWith40GB` and its subdirectory.
From the shell you can

```
mv /home/user/DirWith40GB /mnt/vbd/Dir2
cd /home/user
link ln -s /mnt/vbd/Dir2 DirWith40GB
```

so doing you will restore the original name in the first partition.
Of course when you will do maintenance you will resize the partition and move back the data.

The ***drawbacks*** can be hidden in some options of some commands, (`find`, `rsync`, `tar` ...), when it is specified if to follow (symbolic) links or not, and if to remain on the same partition...
Another problem can arise if the files in `DirWith40GB` are in use...
Moreover it is possible to add an HDD (or a partition) and to mount it under a path (it is normal for the Unix filesystems), but you said you access it only via ssh... so the quick and dirty workaround.

**Further readings**

- You may want to give it a look to  ["What is the difference between a symbolic link and a hard link?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185899/what-is-the-difference-between-a-symbolic-link-and-a-hard-link)